# What's the problem with this sentense, i'm getting 'invalid date' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a timeline chart, so while i am making an array  for it, the problem with 'invalid date' appears, maybe i messed up with .map, cause i don't know ruby well

```rb
status_and_date = StatusVersion.where(requeat_id:812).pluck(status_id, :date).reverse
@requests_timeline = status_and_date.map do  |r,s| 
  s=s.to_s
  for i in 0..s.length-1 
     label = r.to_s 
     start_date = s[i].to_date 
     end_date = s[i+1].to_date
     [label, start_date, end_date] 
     end
  end
  @requests_timeline
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the `status_id` is incremental by 1.
I guess The problem is in your loop, if `i == s.length -1` then, `s[i+1]` will be `nil`
You can use `begin ... rescue` to catch error to see the detail error by modifying your loop using below code

```
for i in 0..s.length-1 
   begin
     label = r.to_s 
     start_date = s[i].to_date 
     end_date = s[i+1].to_date
     [label, start_date, end_date] 
   rescue
     puts "i - #{i}"
     puts "s[i] - #{s[i]}"
     puts "s[i+1] - #{s[i+1]}"
   end
end
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to increment date but you're right about the length that i should use. I erased my code about transforming date to string , so now it looks like that              status_and_date = StatusVersion.where(requeat_id:812).pluck(status_id, :date).reverse
        requests_timeline = status_and_date.map do  |r,s| 

        for i in 0..s.length-1 label = r.to_s start_date = s[i].to_date end_date = s[i+1].to_daate [label, start_date, end_date] end
      end  requests_timeline   But i'm getting an error - undefined method ‘length for date